# "Must not" and "don't have to"

Tags: grammar, verb

Could someone tell me how to say in Korean:

1. **mustn't** *[it is forbidden]* {One mustn't kill people.}
2. **don't have to** *[it isn't forbidden but unnecessary]* {I don't have to clean my room.}

Comment: Can you share what you have tried to find the answer, like a dictionary look up or an incomplete translation?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. I couldn't find the answer anywhere. I tried to look it up in the "Wordreference" dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. mustn't

- 해서는 안 된다
- 하지 말아야 한다
- 하면 (절대) 안 된다
- etc.

E.g.

> - 살인해서는 안 된다.
> - 살인하지 말아야 한다.
> - 살인하면 안 된다.

### 2. don't have to

- (하지 않아도/안 해도) (좋다/된다/괜찮다/...)
- 할 필요(가/는) 없다
- etc. etc.

E.g.

> - 방을 청소할 필요는 없다.
> - 방 청소 안 해도 된다.
> - 방을 청소하지 않아도 괜찮다.

Comment: Sorry, could you indicate the basic form?
Like this: verb stem + an ending.
I can't understand it.
Thank you in advance!